# Create HTTPS service in Mule ESB

Tags: https, mule

I'm trying to make a flow that uses a HTTPS inbound endpoint.

So far I manage to do the following:

- Create the keystore file by terminal with this command:

  `keytool -genkey -alias mule -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks`
- Placed the keystore.jks in my mule app src/main/resources directory
- Created a global HTTPS connector with the following settings:

[image]

- In my HTTP inbound endpoint checked the "Enable HTTPS" checkbox and selected my new global HTTPS connector as the connector reference.

My problem comes when accessing said endpoint in, lets say
    `https://localhost:8082/getProducts`

The browser throws this message

```
SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server,     or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.
```

And in my mule log I have the following:

```
ERROR 2013-04-23 12:08:55,451 [[integrador-catalogogit].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Http Request line is malformed: "�?��?Qv??e]?.�t#?G??*?p?V*????stS��H?"
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: Http Request line is malformed: "�?��?Qv??e]?.�t#?G??*?p?V*????stS��H?"
at org.mule.transport.http.RequestLine.parseLine(RequestLine.java:52)
at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readRequest(HttpServerConnection.java:190)
at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:155)
at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
ERROR 2013-04-23 12:08:55,467 [[integrador-catalogogit].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Http Request line is malformed: "�?��?Qv???P?*?~c?q?6?]??W?[??��H?"
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: Http Request line is malformed: "�?��?Qv???P?*?~c?q?6?]??W?[??��H?"
at org.mule.transport.http.RequestLine.parseLine(RequestLine.java:52)
at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readRequest(HttpServerConnection.java:190)
at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:155)
at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
ERROR 2013-04-23 12:08:55,469 [[integrador-catalogogit].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Http Request line is malformed: "��U��Q�Qv?cN????;]<???-???^S???G[?��*�?�?�?�9�8�?�5�E�D�f�3�2�?�A���/��??�"
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: Http Request line is malformed: "��U��Q�Qv?cN????;]<???-???^S???G[?��*�?�?�?�9�8�?�5�E�D�f�3�2�?�A���/��??�"
at org.mule.transport.http.RequestLine.parseLine(RequestLine.java:52)
at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readRequest(HttpServerConnection.java:190)
at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:155)
at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Probably I'm missing configuration steps either in server side or mule side.

I'll really appreciate the help.

**Edit**:

My XML ends up looking like [this](http://cl.ly/code/2D091x2m1t2q):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="CE-3.3.1" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">
    <https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" proxyHostname="localhost" proxyPort="80" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
        <https:tls-client path="keystore.jks" storePassword="1234"/>
        <https:tls-key-store path="keystore.jks" keyPassword="1234" storePassword="1234"/>
        <https:tls-server path="keystore.jks" storePassword="1234"/>
    </https:connector>
    <flow name="getProducts" doc:name="getProducts">
        <https:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="getProducts" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="Codefuel.parameters.RequestParameters" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <component class="Codefuel.product.mulesoft.GetProductByParameters" doc:name="GetProductByParameters"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Show your XML configuration or we can't help you. An IDE screenshot is not enough.

Comment: "My problem comes when accessing said endpoint" <- How do you access it?

Comment: Initially by posting to it, but the error is present when pasting the URL on the browser and "curling" it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a keystore with the command in your question (with password `123456`, `1234` is too short) and deployed your configuration (except that I removed `json:json-to-object-transformer` and `component`, since I do not have the class) on Mule 3.4 and it works perfectly.

I can `curl -k https://localhost:8082/getProducts` and get a reply. So there must be something else you're not showing that causes trouble.

Comment: Tried that but still no luck

Comment: I've created a keystore with the command in your question (with password 123456, 1234 is too short) and deployed your config (except that I removed `json:json-to-object-transformer` and `component`, since I do not have the class) on Mule 3.4 and it works perfectly. I can `curl -k  https://localhost:8082/getProducts` and get a reply. So there must be something else you're not showing that causes trouble.

Comment: Could it be possible that my server doesn't have correctly configured the Tomcat with a valid SSL certificate, etc?

Comment: Why do you mention Tomcat? Are you running Mule embedded in Tomcat? I'm trying to get the big picture here :)

Comment: Haha yeah sorry, I'm kind of confused myself. 
The way I deploy the app to the server is: 1- I have a mule standalone in the server. 2- I export the mule app as a "Mule Deployable Archive" zip. 3- I paste the zip in the server's mule standolone's apps directory.
I'm not really sure what else besides what I mentioned in the question I need to use the HTTPS. I even tried this locally but not luck either

Comment: Would it be asking too much if you could post the app ZIP somewhere so I can peek into it?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that :(, the app contains lot of my company's work that I cannot reveal; however I could provide config files if that helps.

Comment: OK. Are there more configs than what is above?

Comment: Not really, just an hibernate config and a mule-project__.xml that contains this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mule-project xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.com/tooling/project" runtimeId="org.mule.tooling.server.3.3.1.CE">
    <name>integradorMule</name>
    <description></description>
</mule-project>`

Comment: Sorry I can't really help you: all I can tell is that your approach is correct and your configuration works fine on 3.4.0 :'(

Comment: I really appreciate it though I'll mark your answer as correct since you tested it and it works, I'll keep looking for any detail that might be avoiding this to work, even maybe try with 3.4. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot. Open a new question if you narrow down the issue and can't solve it.

Comment: I finally nailed the problem, I noticed this error while Mule was starting: "Address already in use". For some weird reason this only happened with 8082 port (I'm still not sure what goes around that port), any other port works like a charm =D. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exception :
org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Http Request line is malformed: (crazy charset caracters)

I roll until I realise that my http services were in the same port of https services. Change the port and try again, it works for me.